# How to resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I made a simple java project with hibernate  to understand that  how  hibernate and in hibernate second level cache works but   error has occurred  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory` and i have also added the required jar in the project.

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aikya</property>
    <property name="connection.user">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">123anshu123</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>


    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
        org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
    <property name="dialet">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- enable second level cache and query cache -->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <mapping resource="UserDTO.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2159)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1383)
    at com.dto.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:397)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Are you using Maven?

Comment: No I AM not using maven.